# Create search by tags box

Tags: html, css

I've created a search box with a drop down that displays a certain tag of file type. The fiddle is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/dKCQ5/

The `ul` contains the file tags that need to be searched.

My next step is to create a search by tag option where I'll be clicking on the file type and it'll appear as a search tag similar to the feature on the Evernote web app. More than help in code, are there certain resources that I can use to go forward with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this jQuery-Tags-Input library:

https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

There is a demo on their website:

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

The markup is pretty easy too:

```
<input id="tags" value="dogs,cats" />

$('#tags').tagsInput();
```

Check out my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpatz/cHDa7/).